# HtmlHelp function not working, not opening help file behind a vb button

Tags: vb6, path, html-helper, chm

I am in vb6, behing a button i have put this code:
hwnd is populate correctly. but no help file opens. what could be wrong. the path "D:\software\src\mysoft.chm" opens the help file when i do it from start\run.

```
 abc = "D:\software\src\mysoft.chm"
        HtmlHelp hWnd, abc, HH_HELP_CONTEXT, topic
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found it, the topic in the chm file was erroneous. The chm file needed to be corrected because changing the topid id opened the chm file